# APT CURL etc. expect lower case HTTP_PROXY variables

Tags: apt, proxy, curl

We have 4 (presumably) identical Ubuntu 20.04 machines and one of them expects the environment variables `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY` AND `NO_PROXY` to be lower case.

Programs such as `curl` and `apt` work perfectly on all servers but the one. When we switch `HTTP_PROXY` to `http_proxy` etc that strange server is happy. Before that apt and curl don't see the proxy.

None of the other servers have the lower case versions of these variables.

- What could be the reason that one server expects lower case?
- What could be the reason that all other servers work with lower case?

Comment: Interesting. Whereas environment variables (i.e. exported ones) are by convention written in uppercase, `http_proxy` is one of a few exceptions and should be in lowercase. Why do the other 3 servers work with an uppercase variable, is the real question here.

Comment: Specifically, `curl` should work with `http_proxy` in lowercase only. See `man curl` under the `ENVIRONMENT` heading. `HTTPS_PROXY` and `NO_PROXY` should work both in upper- and lowercase.